# Apache reverse proxy is not accessible from clients who are using only ipv6

Tags: apache, ubuntu, devops, reverse-proxy

I have Apache reverse proxy installed on Ubuntu 22.x, ipv6 is enabled on ubuntu server.
It is working fine from the clients who have enabled ipv4 or both ipv4/ipv6. But it is not working for the clients who have enabled just ipv6. The error is ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerName api.site.com

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://main-server-ip/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://main-server-ip/


Include /etc/letsencrypt/ssl.conf
ServerAlias site.com
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName site.com

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://mainserveripp/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://mainserveripp/

RewriteEngine on


</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

DNS mapping was not done for ipv6. I added AAAA type record :

```
AAAA   api   server-ip6-value    AUTO
```